# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Decimal' is not valid. - issue when Datagridview loads data from DB

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to load data into datagridview in visual basic but getting this error.

Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Decimal' is not valid. - Problem when Datagridview loads data from DB,

Please when writing a response bear in mind I am a complete newbie.

And by the way I have tried to add .ToString after a Value on some of the ,

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Dim i As Integer

    Me.TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value.ToString
    Me.TextBox8.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value.ToString
    Me.TextBox9.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value.ToString
    Me.TextBox11.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value.ToString
    'valoren_code'
    Me.TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value.ToString
    Me.TextBox13.Text = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value.ToString
    Me.TextBox15.Text = DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value.ToString
    Me.TextBox14.Text = DataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value.ToString
    Me.NumericUpDown6.Value = DataGridView1.Item(8, i).Value.ToString
    Me.DateTimePicker2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(9, i).Value.ToString
    Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem = DataGridView1.Item(10, i).Value.ToString
    Me.ComboBox8.SelectedItem = DataGridView1.Item(11, i).Value.ToString
    Me.ComboBox2.SelectedItem = DataGridView1.Item(12, i).Value.ToString
    Me.ComboBox3.SelectedItem = DataGridView1.Item(13, i).Value.ToString
    Me.ComboBox4.SelectedItem = DataGridView1.Item(14, i).Value.ToString
    Me.ComboBox5.SelectedItem = DataGridView1.Item(15, i).Value.ToString
    Me.ComboBox6.SelectedItem = DataGridView1.Item(16, i).Value.ToString
    Me.ComboBox7.SelectedItem = DataGridView1.Item(17, i).Value.ToString
    Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem = DataGridView1.Item(18, i).Value.ToString
    Me.NumericUpDown8.Text = DataGridView1.Item(19, i).Value.ToString
    Me.NumericUpDown7.Text = DataGridView1.Item(20, i).Value.ToString
    Me.NumericUpDown5.Text = DataGridView1.Item(21, i).Value.ToString
    Me.NumericUpDown13.Text = DataGridView1.Item(22, i).Value.ToString
    Me.NumericUpDown14.Value = DataGridView1.Item(23, i).Value.ToString
    'mid_trade_clean_price_proximity
    Me.NumericUpDown15.Value = DataGridView1.Item(24, i).Value.ToString
    Me.NumericUpDown16.Value = DataGridView1.Item(25, i).Value
    Me.TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(26, i).Value.ToString
    Me.ListBox3.SelectedItem = DataGridView1.Item(27, i).Value.ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

`DBNull.Value` means that the database has returned `NULL` for the specific row/column.

This is not a value that can be assigned to a `Decimal`, hence the error.

Now, you could use `Nothing` when you get `DBNull.Value`, but again, this is not something you can assign to a `Decimal` as it is a value type (and all value types have a value and cannot be assigned a `Nohthing`).

Use a *nullable* `Decimal` - `Decimal?` which *can* take a `Nothing` value. Alternatively, test the returned value to see if it is `DBNull.Value` and if it is, don't assign to your `Decimal` (which will default to `0.0`, so you need to decide what is the correct behaviour for your application).

Comment: @user1712552 - How would you do _what_ exactly? Note that you have posted **no code** whatsoever, so we can't be talking about anything concrete.

Comment: How would I use a nullable decimal?

Comment: @user1712552 - I did post that. The syntax is `Decimal?`. You could also search for "nullable decimal". But with the code you posted, you really should simply test for `If xxx = DBNulll.Value Then`.

Comment: I am soo sorry. I really don't understand when you say assign  or or test the value to see if it is DBNuLL.Value - If you mean the value in the database is 0- you are correct.

Comment: @user1712552 - The value in the database is not `0` it is `NULL`. These are different things. If you don't understand what assign or test the value mean, I suggest you pick up a programming book - these are basic concepts.

Comment: So Would i do it like this if  Me.NumericUpDown14.Value = DataGridView1.Item(23, i).Value is DBNULL.Value then ??

Comment: `If DataGridView1.Item(23, i).Value != DBNULL.Value Then` would be the first line. If it is true, then you can assign: `Me.NumericUpDown14.Value = DataGridView1.Item(23, i).Value`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But I still did not understand. I am going to take your advice and dive into a book!

Comment: Done it. Thanks your help without it I would be totally lost. Thanks again!